# How to increase the speed of reading csv in c++

Tags: c++, csv, file

I'm currently doing my project, but the whole program is wasting too much time.

After some tests, I found that the program spend too much time on I/O.

Cause each file has different data size and the I use random elements in my program, so it's hard to read it in advanced.

Hope someone can help me deal with it.

```cpp
vector<string> _csv(string s)
{
    vector<string> arr;
    istringstream delim(s);
    string token;
    int c = 0;
    while (getline(delim, token, ','))
    {
        arr.push_back(token);
        c++;
    }
    return arr;
}

string filename = company[0] + "_RSI" + std::to_string(rsi[j][24]) + ".csv";
// cout << filename << endl;
ifstream inFile(".\\RSI1~256\\" + filename, ios::in);
if (!inFile) {
  cout << "Open failed!" << endl;
  exit(1);
}
string line;
while (getline(inFile, line)) {
  vector<string> a = _csv(line);
  RSI.push_back(atof(a[2].c_str()));
  price.push_back(atof(a[1].c_str()));
  date.push_back(a[0]);
}
```

Comment: Maybe try to save it in binary format? I have no experience with that but may help increase read & write speed.

Comment: "the program spend too much time on I/O". This is not a simple code-fix. The code you show is just pushing the data on vectors. Although reallocation (when resize is needed) takes time, it is negligible with respect to disk access.
What is actually the problem? What do you want to do? Why is the program "wasting too much time"? File access always takes time.

Comment: We can't tell unless you show us the `_csv` function. Also, check you're measuring the release version time, not the debug one.

Comment: If there's an optimization to be made, that's by preloading as much data as you can. Possibly compress it too, instead of using raw CSV.

Comment: Try to use memory mapped files.

Comment: This may not be much, but you are doing three `push_back`, instead, you can define a `object` to store three values and do one `push_back`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a buffer with your `ifstream`. At least the MSVC implementation performs poorly without a buffer.

```
   std::vector<char> buffer(256 * 1024);
   std::ifstream inFile(".\\RSI1~256\\" + filename, std::ios::in);
   inFile.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
```

Note - the statements must be in that exact order as shown to ensure correct buffer lifetime with respect to the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Possible optimization: don't use the CSV files directly, but a compressed cached version that you would uncompress with zlib (or Poco.Zip, or whatever) once loaded.
Depending on your average CSV file content, this could drastically reduce the amount of data you need to load from disk. Maybe your whole database could be loaded in RAM, and some entries selectively uncompressed when needed.

```
└── your-database/
    ├── file0001.csv
    ├── file0002.csv
    ├── ...
    └── cache/
        ├── file0001.csv.zip
        └── file0001.csv.zip
        └── ...
```

Comment: decompressing also takes a (lot of) time... just like loading the files to memory. and maybe he doesn't actually need to cache them, but only read them once.

Comment: It's usually faster to deflate -> store/send -> inflate data when it's not complete random noise and your CPU is somewhat decent.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do some profiling and look into where you spend too much time.

If you spend too much time in the getline calls, you may want to focus on how you get the data into memory, i.e. by reading bigger chunks or using other techniques (OS specific stuff, changing file format, using compression).

If you spend a lot of time in your parser, then consider that at the moment, you parse each line of the CSV file in two passes: first you split up the line (in a way that does not perform well exactly), write everything into a vector, then parse each entry of the vector. This causes a ridiculous amount of unnecessary memory allocations. You can use a more tailor-fitted version of the `_csv` function that uses `std::from_chars` for the parsing and directly writes to the vectors.